# How to extend stepped line area until the edge of graph in Line and Stacked Chart Power BI

Tags: visual-studio, powerbi, linechart

**Goal :**
Stepped cover the whole bar until the edge like below.
[image]

from google spreadsheet

**Problem :**

Cannot find a method or tricks to extend the stepped line until the edge.

[image]

**Data :**

```
Type    YTD in TGT  RF  GAP OVER
A       80          90  20  
B       110         105      10
```

How can we solve this dirty situations whatever some way to dig down with developer mode in visual studio code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much you can do. PowerBI do not include the source of their visuals so you cant dive in to the "code behind".

You may get some improvement adjusting the X-Axis settings (padding). See inage below. You can also look in the visuals in the marketplace which may have some options though I haven't seen one that looks suitable. Alternatively you can build your own custom visual - which requires a lot of time and effort.

My recommendation is to try and stick to the standard PowerBI visuals and capabilities. It is not a custom dev tool and if you try to do pixel perfect reports as per a designer spec or business requirement you are going to continually bump up in to a lot of complexity. If demand is for full customisation of the UI and/or UX, then consider a different approach using custom dev from the ground up. The expense of this is often prohibitive and, once explained, using the out of the box PowerBI features becomes a little more palatable.

[image: Adjusting Padding]